# How to allow access to only a single file?

Tags: apache

I have a apache machine which is serving a `.js` file. That file should be the only file that need to seen.

I have configured to do so in my apache like this :

```
<Location /var/www/test/test.js>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

The site address is `test.in` which points to `test.js` file in `/var/www/test` directory. That is working fine. But I wish when the user tries to hit `test.in/someurl` (which is not available) or some other url than `test.in` need to give an message with `401` error.

How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17):

> **NOTE:** This Answer only applies to Version 2.2
>
> If you are using Version 2.4 take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration) or Look at the official [Apache Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access)

You misused `<Location>` - the argument should be URI not the directory path... You should use `<Directory>` to get the expected behavior.

I would do something like this (you should finetune it, it shows just the principle):

```
# first deny access to everything
<Location />
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from All
</Location>

# then allow access to specific URL
<Location /test/test.js>
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from All
</Location>
```

Have a look on [Order](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) directive and one or more of following: [Location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location), [LocationMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch), [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory), [DirectoryMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directorymatch), [Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files), [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch), etc.

Comment: I would like to straighten up one minor detail, it's not URL you are referring to - its URI