# Apache2: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'

Tags: server, apache2, apache2.4

I get this error when trying to access localhost via a browser.

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration
```

I checked my site folder permissions using:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R *
```

Here is my configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /home/user-name/www/myproject
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location />
  Allow from all
  Order Deny,Allow
</Location>

<Directory  /home/user-name/www/myproject/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride all
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Comment: Are you using the new Apache 2.4? Which path gives that error?

Comment: Yes, Apache 2.4, and this happens when I'm trying to browse to any file within the app directory

Comment: It seems you need to update your configurations.

Take a look here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time

Comment: I already did that, but I noticed that it is working when the project in /var/www but when it was moved to another path this happens, so I created a symbolic link to my project in /var/www

Comment: "server configuration" -> explicitly not filesystem permissions.

Comment: `chmod 777` is a very bad habit, even if (supposedly) only being used in examples.

Comment: Where is the `VirtualHost` element closed?

Comment: chmod 777 is never the answer.

Comment: if you are using any out of the box configured stack like bitnami on aws, PLEASE do a `sudo httpd  -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES` and read CAREFULLY that the correct configuration files are included.  In my case the location of the httpd-app.conf was wrong the httpd-vhosts.conf.  I was editing the wrong file for *hours* before I figured this out.

Answer (score 886, accepted):

If you are using Apache 2.4

You have to check allow and deny rules

Check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access

> In 2.2, access control based on client hostname, IP address, and other
>   characteristics of client requests was done using the directives
>   Order, Allow, Deny, and Satisfy.
>
> In 2.4, such access control is done in the same way as other
>   authorization checks, using the new module mod_authz_host.

The new directive is [Require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require):

2.2 configuration:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

2.4 configuration:

```
Require all granted
```

Also don't forget to restart the apache server after these changes (`# service httpd restart`)

Comment: Works of OSX 10.10 Yosemite using Apache 2.4

Comment: Configuration of *what* (i.e. where does "Require all granted" go? In some .conf file?)

Comment: @Alexis directory (or location). See screenshot in next answer.

Comment: In my case I have error in `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` paths.

Comment: One thing to note: if you are referring a configuration online, chances are they've used both `Order allow,deny ...` and `Require all granted`. It'll not work. It needs to be only one of these depending on your version. That's what was stopping me from resolving my issue at first.

Comment: Also, for Wamp 3 (Apache 2.4) in the `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file you might need to replace `Require local` with `Require all granted`

Comment: thanks for the tip. Managed to get apache working again after upgrading to High Sierra

Comment: Like how you included the 2.4 version, that's what got me (coming from an old Apache background).

Comment: I had to reload with `sudo service apache2 reload` on Xubuntu. I got this error: `Failed to restart httpd.service: Unit httpd.service not found.` for httpd service.

Comment: Wouldn't be nice if "configcheck" would check the config :).

Answer (score 326):

For all directories write `Require all granted` instead of `Allow from all`
[image: Something like]

**Update**

If the above doesn't work then also remove this below mentioned line:

> Order allow,deny

Comment: Worked for me once I had removed the `Order allow,deny` line as well.

Comment: Attention: while using **HTTPS**, configuring a **VirtualHost** for port **443**, I had to replicate the same configs  `<Location /media> Require all granted </Location>` on `default-ssl.conf` for my CSS to be loaded. (My problem was that the login page was accessible, but no CSS nor other media files were loaded...)

Comment: Works of OSX 10.10 Yosemite using Apache 2.4

Comment: Am I the only one who HATES it when someone breaks Apache configurations without any output in the log.  (Hey boys, `Allow from All` has been retired because .... reasons...)

Answer (score 48):

Double check that the DocumentRoot path is correct. That can cause this error.

Comment: More specifically, I found this was my problem because I had no trailing slash in my DocumentRoot declaration, but did use one in the `<Directory>` block. I also had some case differences. Once I made these two values carbon copies of each other (without the trailing slash), it worked perfectly.

Comment: If that's the case (yes, also happened here....) you can find the follwing line in `apache/logs/error.log`: `AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [E:/xampp/htdocs/website/frontend/web] does not exist`

Comment: Cant believe I can find answers for my typo mistakes as well :-) Thanks for bringing it up, my issue was the  invalid path in my conf file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice! A zillion times I already configured an Apache and this comment saved my night!

Answer (score 28):

I made the same changes that ravisorg suggested to OSX 10.10 Yosemite that upgrades Apache to version 2.4. Below are the changes that were added to http.conf.

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /Volumes/Data/Data/USER/Sites/>
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem is in VirtualHost but **probablely is not**

> Require all granted

**Confirm** your **config** is correct,here is correct sample
[image]

Comment: Including the `<Directory ...> ... </Directory>` lines worked for me since I was using a directory path that wasn't previously defined in Apache configurations before.

Comment: Same for me - the issue was the DocumentRoot was pointing outside the standard locations defined in the Apache configs, and needed that Require directive specified for the new/alternate path.

Answer (score 12):

This drove me absolutely nuts for a day and a half but I found a solution if all other solutions have been tried unsuccessfully.

This is for macOS.

- Go to activity Monitor (spotlight search for: activity)
- In activity monitor search for httpd which is the Apache service
- Select the one that belongs to root and click X on the top left to close it.

At that point I immediately stopped getting 403 errors and everything started working as expected. Weird thing is i didn't even have to restart apache it just worked, i guess it restarted itself when i went to my localhost, I honestly don't know but I guess the problem is Apache not actually restarting when using apachectl restart, or stop or start. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: After hours of wasted time this is what solved my issues too.

Answer (score 11):

For me, all proposed solutions won't worked. This can help, if you use cgi, fastcig or fpm as proxy you have to add a location in your vhost to avoid this problem. This allows 404 to be passthrough proxy.

```
<Location />
require all granted
</Location>
```

Comment: thanks apache is really a PITA when it comes to understanding the exact cause of error... leaves 0 room for exploration/trial and error

Comment: for whatever reason, my HTTPS was ok, but HTTP was not. Adding this solved the issue

Comment: now, my HTTP doesn't seem to be doing mod_rewrite ‍♂️

Answer (score 5):

in my case,

i'm using macOS Mojave (Apache/2.4.34). There was an issue in virtual host settings at /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file. after adding the required directory tag my problem was gone.

Require all granted

Hope the full virtual host setup structure will save you.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/vagabond/Sites/MainProjectFolderName/public/"
    ServerName project.loc

    <Directory /Users/vagabond/Sites/MainProjectFolderName/public/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/Users/vagabond/Sites/logs/MainProjectFolderName.loc-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/vagabond/Sites/logs/MainProjectFolderName.loc-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

all you've to do replace the MainProjectFolderName with your exact ProjectFolderName.

Answer (score 4):

If you tail the error log and reload the page, you should see some more information as to the exact problem.

Grab the environment variables so ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} will actually work...

```
source /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Then tail and watch...

```
tail -f ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

Comment: This is the error from logs: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'

Comment: You'll probably be wanting to check this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759854/client-denied-by-server-configuration-while-trying-to-use-git-http-backend-exe

Comment: If you add `LogLevel debug` to the VirtualHost this is good advice, as you'll then see lines like "Require all denied: denied", and "<RequireAny>: denied" (i.e. much more useful than just "client denied by server configuration", as it actually tells you *which* configuration!)

Answer (score 4):

I got resolved my self after spending couple of hours.

I installed Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) through coookbook in vagrant vm.

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf file does not have `<VirtualHost *:80>` element by default.

I did two changes to get it done

1. added `<VirtualHost *:80>`
2. added
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride all
   Allow from all

then finally I just booted vm..

Answer (score 4):

Has anyone thought about that wamp server default not include the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.
My approach is to remove the note below

```
 conf
  # Virtual hosts
  Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

in `httpd.conf` file.
That is all.

Comment: +1 This worked for me as well but maybe a better solution is to keep the `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file and replace in it `Require local` with `Require all granted`

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem when setting up virtual hosts on a new server, and having the sites hosted outside of the standard /var/www/html path. There are two main things that you need to consider (and for example purposes, let's say you are setting up a site in /opt/my-site)

On a default 2.4 installation, there is an explicit denial of access to the root filesystem, and then it only gives access to /var/www/html.   So you'll need to give the web server access to read from the new directory with something like this:

```
<Directory /opt/mysite>
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Once you've done that, then make sure the DocumentRoot for your virtual host is somewhere under that path you've granted access to above.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName neatwebsite.com
        DocumentRoot /opt/my-site/html
</VirtualHost>
```

When I ran into this problem, I had all the VirtualHosts set up fine, but forgot to allow read from the directory structure (so I was missing the  directive).   You'll need to consider both these directives, and how they work together.

Answer (score 3):

This was driving me crazy. Finally figured out what the problem was:
I was using direct paths for the error log and they were wrong.

Why does Apache give a vague (and wrong) error message? Instead use a correct and useful error message like: Path for ErrorLog directive "/wrong/path/and/filename.log" is invalid.

Anyway, to fix make sure your error log directives look something like this:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: You were right... If you only set `ErrorLog` but not `CustomLog` then it breaks. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Apache 2.4 in WampServer on windows OS.

You need to open **https-vhosts.conf** file in notepad.

```
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.37\conf\extra\https-vhosts.conf
```

If you unable to find above file. check screenshot below
[image: Wampserver apacche 2.4 httpd-vhosts]

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
     <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In above code Replace

```
Require local
```

with

```
Require all granted
```

And save it. Restart Apache service and try again.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had actually updated the Allow and Deny rules based on the 2.4 standard.

```
Require all granted
```

However, this was still causing me to receive the same AH01630 error. I found another thread and it suggested reinstalling apache2. Somehow this worked! If anyone cares to explain why, that would be helpful.

Credit to: [AH01630: client denied by server configuration but require all granted is set (Apache 2.4, CentOs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117745/ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration-but-require-all-granted-is-set-a)

Answer (score 3):

```
...
<IfVersion < 2.4>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
   Require all granted
</IfVersion>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have https host then don't forget to make `Require all granted` changes for ssl config too.

Also, sometimes it's useful to check permissions as the apache user:

```
# ps -eFH | grep http # get the username used by httpd
...
apache   18837  2692  0 119996 9328   9 10:33 ?        00:00:00     /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
# su -s/bin/bash apache # switch to that user
bash-4.2$ whoami
apache
bash-4.2$ cd /home
bash-4.2$ ls
bash-4.2$ cd mysite.com
bash-4.2$ ls
bash-4.2$ cat file-which-does-not-work.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

When using Ubuntu check whether the CGI module is enabled. If not:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
```

Comment: CGI module needed to be enabled. Program finally worked.

Answer (score 2):

## Ensure that any user-specific configs are included!

If none of the other answers on this page for you work, here's what I ran into after hours of floundering around.

I used user-specific configurations, with `Sites` specified as my `UserDir` in `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`. However, I was forbidden access to the endpoint `http://localhost/~jwork/`.

I could see in `/var/log/apache2/error_log` that access to `/Users/jwork/Sites/` was being blocked. However, I was permitted to access the DocumentRoot, via `http://localhost/`. This suggested that I didn't have rights to view the `~jwork` user. But as far as I could tell by `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` and `lsof -i :80`, Apache was running for the `jwork` user, so something was clearly not write with my user configuration.

Given a user named `jwork`, here was my config file:

### `/private/etc/apache2/users/jwork.conf`

```
<Directory "/Users/jwork/Sites/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This config is perfectly valid. However, I found that my user config wasn't being included:

### `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`

```
## Note how it's commented out by default.
## Just remove the comment to enable your user conf.
#Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

Note that this is the default path to the userdir conf file, but as you'll see below, it's configurable in `httpd.conf`. Ensure that the following lines are enabled:

### `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# ...

LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who stuck at this error as me and nothing helped from above: check if problem folder from error.log actually exists on your server. Mine was generated automatically by Django in wrong place (was messed with static root, then `manage.py collectstatic`). Have no idea why one can not name errors correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved this one by adding the directory access to the :80 entry.

```
 <Directory "c:/whatever-directory-you-use/">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Before everyone gets all 'security' on me, under my specific circumstances this is not a security issue.

If you are using a remote resource, I'd recommend instead make sure your CURL request goes via HTTPS / TLS, then this directory entry goes on the 443 port.

Answer (score 2):

Because this thread is the first thing that pops up when searching for the error mentioned I would like to add another possible cause for this error: you may have `mod_evasive` active and the client seeing this error simply has crossed the limits configured in your `mod_evasive.conf`

This is especially a cause worth investigating if you are suddenly getting this error for a client that had no problems before and nothing else has changed.

(if `mod_evasive` is the cause then the error will go away by itself if the client just temporarily stops trying to access the site; however it may be a sign that you have configured too tight limits)

Answer (score 1):

For Wamp 3 (Apache 2.4), besides putting the server online as described in the other answers, in the Virtual Hosts file `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
you might need to replace

```
Require local
```

with

```
Require all granted
```

This is applicable if in `httpd.conf` you have

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside missing `Order` and `Allow` directives mentioned in other answers be aware that a non-matching regular expression of a `DirectoryMatch` directive may also cause this error.

If the requested path is `/home/user-foo1bar/www/myproject/` the folloing matcher won't match

```
<DirectoryMatch "/home/user-[a-z]+/www/myproject/">
...
</DirectoryMatch>
```

thus, even a valid access configuration might cause this error.

Answer (score 1):

Get solution for the issue, need to change in apache2.conf file after that it will works,
old code in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

changed in to

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

after that, In order for Apache to understand rewrite rules, we first need to activate mod_rewrite. It's already installed, but it's disabled on a default Apache installation. Use the a2enmod command to enable the module:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

This will activate the module or alert you that the module is already enabled. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

it works for me finally.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are like me and tried all the answers above and none helped, remember to check if your `apache2.conf` has a line like `IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf` and then check each of the .conf files in that folder.

Mine had a `security.conf` file that included this section (which needed to be removed/modified to not block the .php files I needed to run):

```
<FilesMatch "^(wp-config\.php|php\.ini|php5\.ini|install\.php|php\.info|readme\.md|README\.md|readme\.html|bb-config\.php|\.htaccess|\.htpasswd|readme\.txt|timthumb\.php|error_log|error\.log|PHP_errors\.log|\.sv$
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

I don't know where that file came from unless at some point I went down a rabbit hole of trying to secure my apache configuration, found this conf, added it, and then totally forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

One obscure (having just dealt with it), yet possible, cause of this is an internal mod_rewrite rule, in the main config file (not .htaccess) that writes to a path which exists at the root of the server file system. Say you have a `/media` directory in your site, and you rewrite something like this:

```
RewriteRule /some_image.png /media/some_other_location.png
```

If you have a `/media` directory at the root of your server, the rewrite will be attempted to that (resulting in the access denied error) rather than the one in your site directory, since the file system root is checked first by mod_rewrite, for the existence of the first directory in the path, before your site directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that directive is not under < Directory>

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#requiredirectives

The directive can be referenced within a < Directory>, < Files>, or < Location> section as well as .htaccess files to control access to particular parts of the server. Access can be controlled based on the client hostname or IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I got another one that may be useful to someone.
Was receiving the same error message after upgrading from PHP 5.6 => 7.0. We had changed the PHP upload settings, and forgot to change once copied over. 
Even though i wasn't uploading images at the time, Silverstripe (our CMS) was refusing to save and throwing that error. Increased the image upload size and it worked straight away.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone Googling around like I was, I had this error message trying to access a SVG file on my server, e.g. https://example.com/images/file.svg.  Other file types seemed fine, just SVG were failing.

I hunted around `/etc/httpd` conf files and checked every `require all denied` type of configuration, and just could not find what config was having this effect.

I turned LogLevel to debug in the VirtualHost config and could see the mod_authz_core logging specifying there was a 'Require all denied' in effect:

```
[Mon Jun 10 13:09:54.321022 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 23459:tid 140576341206784] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 127.0.0.1:54626] AH01626: authorization result of Require all denied: denied
[Mon Jun 10 13:09:54.321038 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 23459:tid 140576341206784] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 127.0.0.1:54626] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied
[Mon Jun 10 13:09:54.321082 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 23459:tid 140576341206784] [client 127.0.0.1:54626] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/blah/htdocs/images/file.svg
```

Through blind testing I moved the file to the root of the web root, and found I could then access it at https://example.com/file.svg .. so it only failed in the 'images' folder.  This led me to an .htaccess file in the images folder that I had no idea was there.

Turns out Zen Cart 1.5 comes with an images/.htaccess file that has:

```
# deny *everything*
 <FilesMatch ".*">
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     Require all denied
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     Order Allow,Deny
     Deny from all
   </IfModule>
 </FilesMatch>

 # but now allow just *certain* necessary files:
 <FilesMatch "(?i).*\.(jpe?g|gif|webp|png|swf)$" >
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     Require all granted
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from all
   </IfModule>
 </FilesMatch>
```

This was *very annoying* and I hope this might remind others to check .htaccess files at every level of the file system leading to the file you're having trouble accessing in case there is this kind of tom foolery going on.

Answer (score 0):

This "bug" is actually the new normal behavior of Apache 2.4. In my case, I had a very specific rule to deny access to any folder or file with name starting with ".", so I had to set an exception for a particular public folder that requires such odd name.

For the record my particular Rewrite rule is:

`RewriteRule "(?!\.trusted)(^|/)\." - [F]`

This rule [F]obits everything starting with "." but `.trusted`, thanks to the magic of regex "?!" negation.

Answer (score 0):

For me I needed to remove all `.htaccess` in my wordpress folder. (Files that you don't see when you just look in the folder with `ls -lh`)