# Why doesn't this Apache virtualhost entry work?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm running Apache 2.4.6 on Ubuntu 13.

In sites-available, I have a conf file for my site that contains only this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin somebody@somewhere.com
  ServerName  www.ourco.me
  ServerAlias ourco.me

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/ouruser/public/ourco.me/public

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/ouruser/public/ourco.me/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/ouruser/public/ourco.me/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

There are no other conf files enabled.  When I have use apachectl -S to display the sites, it shows:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.ourco.me (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ourco.me.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.ourco.me (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ourco.me.conf:1)
                 alias ourco.me
         port 80 namevhost www.ourco.me (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ourco.me.conf:1)
                 alias ourco.me
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

The first thing I notice is the duplicate entry for namevhost www.ourco.me.  And when I visit the site in a browser, I get:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at www.ourco.me Port 80

All the directories and files specified in the conf file exist. a2ensite and a2dissite work as expected to add/remove a symlink for this file from sites-enabled, so it's looking at the right file.  Does anyone know why its directives are being ignored?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Put Allow from all

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin somebody@somewhere.com
  ServerName  www.ourco.me
  ServerAlias ourco.me

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/ouruser/public/ourco.me/public

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/ouruser/public/ourco.me/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/ouruser/public/ourco.me/log/access.log combined
 Allow from all
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. The result is: AH00526: Syntax error on line 16 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ourco.me.conf:
allow not allowed here
Action 'configtest' failed.

Comment: "Require all granted", which appears to be the new syntax, also fails with a similar message.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to solve the problem:

```
<Directory />
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

when placed in the VirtualHost entry.

That snippet came from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration).  I'm looking at [this Apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) to see why it works.