# Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) AH01630: client denied by server configuration despite "Require all granted"

Tags: apache, authentication, ubuntu, configuration

I've got error:

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 20259] [client 127.0.0.1:45677] AH01630: client denied by server     configuration: /home/user/www/myhost.dev
```

and 403 Forbidden

in  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) of course I added Require all granted

my configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName myhost.dev

ServerAdmin admin@myhost.dev

DocumentRoot /home/user/www/myhost.dev/web

<Directory /home/user/www/myhost.dev/web>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.myhost.dev.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel notice

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.myhost.dev.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem may be found in [Apache2: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration) Hope it help you

basically you need to take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html