# 403 - Forbidden: Trying to get WordPress to Run on AWS

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, terminal

I am trying to get WordPress running on AWS, and I keep getting the following error.

403 - Forbidden:
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I have installed PHP on the server, used Filezilla to add the files to AWS, and have gotten Apache to reference the proper location.

In terminal, I am getting this issue:

```
[Mon May 04 17:39:59.709131 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 9239] [client 000.000.000.00:2935] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/www/
```

I realize there are a lot of problems this could be caused by, but I'm wondering what it could potentially be because I have exhausted the options I am aware of.

Comment: Have you used chmod from the Linux command line to ensure the files are have readable access by the public?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration

Comment: Looks like permission do not allow Apache to access the folder. I would using `chmod` to 755, or move the site folder to another location that is not your primary user. Something like `/var/sites/www`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar issue on a Beanstalk Wordpress. Following the AWS tutorial it would appear that your site would be accessible through the Elastic Beanstalk URL, but you had to add the full path [your Elastic Beanstalk URL]/wordpress-elasticbeanstalk.
Wordpress was accessible there. So maybe playing with copying your files to other location and trying to access that location.