# apache + symlinks = 403

Tags: apache, symlink, http-status-code-403

So I've been reading up a lot on the subject but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I also tried a couple solutions found here but still...
I have multilple vhosts set up with Apache, everything working fine serving different files from both `/home/usr1/html` and `/home/usr2/html`.

Now I symlinked `/home/usr1/html/thisfolder` to `/home/usr2/html/thatfolder`, double checked the FollowSymlinks option is enabled both in *apache2.conf* and in *vhost.conf*, but I'm getting a **403 Error**.

Why should this be about permits? I mean, `www-data` can read without any problem from both folders, how is it that when symlinked it just doesn't?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

**Error returned by Apache:** *(notice the missing script filename, only extension is provided)*

```
[Wed Apr 20 12:13:11.297208 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 19883] [client 192.168.0.1:12345] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/usr2/html/thatfolder/.php
```

**Virtual Host conf file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName server.domain.lan
ServerAdmin adm@lan
DocumentRoot /home/usr2/html

<Directory /home/usr2/html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/usr1/html/thisfolder> // original folder
        Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have `Options +FollowSymlinks`  set in the config or the local .htaccess?

Comment: just tried, doesn't change a bit. altough I was under the impression that when enabled in the __.conf__ files it wasn't necessary to specify it on __.htaccess__...

Comment: Yes, when enabled in the conf, it shouldn't be necessary there. Can you look in the error log what the exact message is?

Comment: `[Wed Apr 20 12:13:11.297208 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 19883] [client 192.168.0.1:12345] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/usr2/html/folder/.php`  
please notice the fact there is no script filename, just the extension.

Comment: Googling that error message suggests the problem might not be the symlink, but a different misconfiguration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration

Comment: as soon as I posted the error I googled for the code and read the very same question. unfortunately the _Require all granted_ directive is set already (on the vhost.conf)

Comment: But is the ``Require all granted`` set for directories which are the target of the symlinks as well as the directory containing the symlinks.

Comment: just added the `<dir /dir/symlink_orig>require</dir>` to vhost to no avail...

Comment: You meant `Require all granted`, correct? And just to rule out all possibilities: you know that conf changes require a server restart, right?

Comment: turns out it was an `.htaccess` rule messing things up, I had all .php files stripped of their extension, resulting in apache trying to get /thatfolder.php instead of /thatfolder/index.php