# Using EBS for the www/http directory

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a simple web server set up on an ec2 instance.

I want to use a separate EBS disk to store the websites it hosts.

I have created and mounted a disk at /data and can access it via SSH and ftp.

But when i try to serve websites from it by specifying a folder there in vhosts, I get the standard apache page.

I think it might be something to do with permissions / ownership of the directory but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any advice?

Comment: whats your apache configuration for the virtual host referencing those folders. If you had pbm with permission you'll receive a specific error, do you have any error in your access/error log ?

Comment: here's part of the vhosts:

<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName default:80

  DocumentRoot /data/html

  #ServerAdmin you@example.com

  #ErrorLog /data/vhosts/logs/error_log

</VirtualHost>

works fine for /var/www/html but when i change it to /data/html it stops working

Comment: nothing in the error log, but that's also on /data so might be unable to write

Comment: can anyone read on `/data/html` ?

Comment: [Wed Jun 22 10:02:12.514341 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 9185] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:47391] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /data/$

Comment: changed the log location and now get that error

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: you need to add the folder you want to serve from (in my case /data) in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/data">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```