# Strange 500 error localhost WordPress install

Tags: wordpress, apache, localhost, mamp

Ok so this happened to me the other day and I was able to resolve it by reinstalling WordPress, my WordPress theme and all of its plugins (took forever)

It has now happened again so I need to get to the root of the issue.

I have a website running on my localhost (using MAMP)

When I visit localhost:8888/ I am able to access my entire file directory.

All other sites on my localhost are loading without issue, except for the site I need to access. I am getting a 500 error in the browser.

When I enable WP Debug it doesn't change from the 500 error in the browser.

I have not modified this site in any way to cause this issue, it literally just randomly bricks itself. The same thing happened before to the exact same site.

I have gone through a ton of guides and am completely lost at what is causing the issue.

Would really appreciate some help troubleshooting.

This is my latest error log from apache.

```
    [Tue Jul 05 14:43:49 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Tue Jul 05 14:43:52 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
    [Tue Jul 05 14:43:52 2016] [notice] Digest: done
    [Tue Jul 05 14:43:52 2016] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 1372)
    [Tue Jul 05 14:43:52 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.5.23 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zh DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Jul 05 14:44:05 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Tue Jul 05 14:44:07 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
    [Tue Jul 05 14:44:07 2016] [notice] Digest: done
    [Tue Jul 05 14:44:07 2016] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 1414)
    [Tue Jul 05 14:44:07 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.6.7 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zh DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Jul 05 16:48:35 2016] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/brettgolding/Google Drive/htdocs/.DS_Store
```

Comment: what's the status of your .htaccess file?

Comment: It seems like an issue with your .htaccess file.Have you changed the settings in your .htaccess file ?

Comment: I couldn't locate a .htaccess file in my directory so I went ahead and created one, to no effect. I also reinstalled WordPress manually to no effect.

Comment: Sometimes when you install wordpress it may or may not create an .htaccess file. Something definitely changed when you last used it. It could be MAMP or it can also be your Apache not having AllowOverride to All.

Comment: Go to the WP Dashboard --> Settings --> Permalinks. Click on default and save changes.

Comment: I'm not sure, I've gone through so many guides addressing the apache conf file. Here is my entire httpd.conf file from the conf > apache directory. http://pastebin.com/reH8F15p

Comment: unixmiah I can't access the WordPress admin panel

Comment: did you change or upgrade apache? if you did you need to make the changes for that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116543/discussion-between-brettgolding-and-unixmiah).