# Apache: clarifying a file's / directory's existance

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website with a url that uses `mod_rewrite` to rewrite the files (all in the same folder).

The url is this shape: `/sales/<category>`

And this is translated by mod_rewrite below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sales/([a-z0-9A-Z\-]+)/?$ /sales/boatlist.php?folder=$1 [NC,L]
```

So the destination file on the server is:

> ```
> /sales/boatlist.php?folder=yachts
> ```

**However, here is my issue.**

When this exact category is requested (`sales/yachts`), the page that is loaded is an apache ***forbidden*** reply, and the PHP is not loaded at all; `boatlist.php` is not called. I deduce from this that there is a file or folder in the directory (therefore escaping the `mod_rewrite` via the `RewriteCond`) that is marked as forbidden, 
**however on the server no file/folder exists with this name** and no other mod_rewrites would relate (and shouldn't return 403 forbidden reply even if they did).

I have found server error logs stating:

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /farm/site/public/sales/yachts

And have obviously [researched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration) [this error](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration) and found it doesn't seem to apply, as my Apache version is 2.4.25 (and has been installed for a long time) and has the current httpd.conf of:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options All
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

As far as I can trace, nothing has been updated in the recent days to suddenly cause this issue, but more so, the issue only occurs for a specific url; not for any other URLs, rewritten or not.

> http://site.co.uk/sales/dinghies Works. 
>   http://site.co.uk/sales/yachts returns error 403 when no file exists.

## What Can I do to further investigate and establish (*solve*) what's going on here?

*(The PHP file the (rewritten) url reaches works perfectly when typed in manually.)*

### EDIT

Full `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?msg=404
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?msg=403
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?msg=500
Options -Indexes

#Set asset items to cache for 1 week.
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js|swf)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1972800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

#force requests to begin with a slash.
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^$
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/
RewriteRule  .*              -    [R=403,L]

#disabled for subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#if not a file or dir then use as a boat details page variable.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^boats/(\d+)-?([\w-]+)/?$  /sales/boatdetails.php?boatid=$1 [NC,L]

#if not a file or dir then use as a boatlist page variable.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sales/([a-z0-9A-Z\-]+)/?$ /sales/boatlist.php?folder=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

<Files php.ini>
Require all denied
</Files>

<LimitExcept GET POST HEAD>
    deny  from all
</LimitExcept>
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava . for `/foo/` this outputs `/bar` (as expected). All other paths work as expected with the URL. The `mod_rewrite` doesn't seem to be broadly at fault, as far as I can tell, the issue is too specific. **EDIT**: with the full url this rule does not  get met.

Comment: Ah yes; rewrite engine is turned on automatically in httpd.conf so it doesn't appear in the htaccess. I will add it in for clarity.

Comment: Ok it seems restart solved your problem.. weird

Comment: @anubhava, thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning I ran automatic server update software (updating plugins for the server *only*) and rebooted Apache.

Apache did not update (so still the same version) but various plugins were updated and after restarting Apache the issue has disappeared.

I still do not know what caused this apparent confusion on the part of Apache.