# Sub pages and directories

Tags: html, apache, subdirectory

I want to create a sub directory within my public_html for organizational purposes. I created a folder called news and I placed a file called index.html but when I visit /news/ I get a forbidden error

> You don't have permission to access /news/.html on this server.

If you navigate to /new/index it brings the page up. Since it appears to be looking for news/.html I tried renaming the file .html but still had no luck.

When I check the logs this is the error I get

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache2: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration)

Comment: The first bit is weird tho. Do you get redirect to this `.html` file? Inspect the headers in Chrome developer tools and see if you notice any 301 or 302. Another potential issue would be you set `.html` in the `DirectoryIndex` directive, instead of the default `index.html` or `index.htm`

Comment: Its an error 403, I haven't changed anything in the DirectoryIndex is there something I should do there?

Comment: So after I removed this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]` from my .htaccess file everything began working as normal. @Capsule