# Is it possible to have a separate cname record for each subdomain on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I'd like to have `www.example.com`, `staging.example.com` and `demo.example.com`, where each of those maps to a separate environment for the same application on Elastic Beanstalk.

Is this possible?

On my hosted zone for `example.com.`, I've setup cname records for `www.example.com`, `staging.example.com` and `demo.example.com` with each having a value that points to their respective EB url.

The first one I setup `www.example.com` works and requests reach the environment. But when I try to reach the others with `ping staging.example.com`, the results is `ping: cannot resolve staging.example.com: Unknown host`.

- Domain purchased and zone hosted on Route 53
- Cert issued on AWS certificate manager
- I've set the certificates the same way on each load balancer
- The first, `www.example.com` works fine
- The others don't
- I'm not sure what I'm missing here unless its not possible

Is this possible to get working?

Note: I've substituted my actual domain for `example.com`.

## **UPDATES 1:**

I might be getting closer but its not working yet, it's returning `You don't have permission to access /user`.

Per this link, https://serverfault.com/questions/407961/setting-up-subdomains-within-amazon-aws-elastic-beanstalk.

I added:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      NameVirtualHost *:80

      <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/app/current/"
         <Directory "/var/app/current/">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
         </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>

      <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName staging.example.com
       DocumentRoot "/var/app/current/your-new-webroot"
        <Directory "/var/app/current/your-new-webroot">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
        </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>
```

Now when I run `ping staging.example.com`, the response is:

> PING
>   example...elasticbeanstalk.com
>   (35.182.128.147): 56 data bytes

Which is great. But when I try to make my actual request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer ..." -d '{}' https://staging.example.com/user
```

The response is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /user
on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

## **UPDATES 2:**

I've reordered my VirtualHosts and added ServerName so it now looks like this:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      NameVirtualHost *:80

      <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName staging.example.com
       DocumentRoot "/var/app/current/your-new-webroot"
        <Directory "/var/app/current/your-new-webroot">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
        </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>

      <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/app/current/"
         <Directory "/var/app/current/">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
         </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>
```

But I'm still getting the same response from my `POST` request:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /user
on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

**Additionally, per my `/var/log/httpd/error_log` logs:**

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/app
```

## **UPDATES 3:**

A couple points.

1. Updated the `Directory` and `DocumentRoot` to point to where my app files are actually stored on the server for my flask app, `"/opt/python/current/app"`, previously I copied and pasted `"/var/app/current/"`.
2. Checked my apache version with `httpd -v`. The result is, `Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Amazon) \n Server built:   Sep 24 2017 23:19:50`

Updated file:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      NameVirtualHost *:80

      <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName staging.example.com
       DocumentRoot "/opt/python/current/app"
        <Directory "/opt/python/current/app">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
        </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>

      <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/python/current/app"
         <Directory "/opt/python/current/app">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
         </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>
```

Still getting the same results.

Comment: DNS changes might take time to propagate. You should rather use `nslookup` and configure it with DNS server orovided by AWS

Comment: have you read : https://serverfault.com/questions/407961/setting-up-subdomains-within-amazon-aws-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: I've updated per reading that post.

Answer (score 1):

The `ping staging.example.com` works because your CNAME resolved properly. However, the `VirtualHost` directive is applied in a linear manner. Since your first `VHost` section does not contain a `ServerName`, it is applied by default to all the requests.

Change the order of both `VHost` sections, or add a `ServerName` to them all, and things should start working (restart of the EB application might be required).

You can also check the log files on the machine itself, if there is some other reason for the 403 error though.

Comment: > _You can also check the log files on the machine itself, if there is some other reason for the 403 error though_. @tim_xyz

Comment: I posted these logs, `/var/log/httpd/error_log`. Are there others I should look at? Apologies but I'm not too familar with infrastructure configuration.

Comment: Ok, it could be a simple apache version mismatch. @tim_xyz can you confirm if you are indeed using apache 2.4 or later? If not, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19588786/1190388

Comment: I've checked the apache version. Its `Apache/2.4.27`. Updated my vhost file to the proper `Directory "/opt/python/current/app"`, and reviewed that SO post. Is there anything else I might want to try?