# Permission denied when trying to access file on Apache

Tags: php, apache

I try to run very basic `php` app using `apache` and `docker compose` and have a problem with `apache` settings. When I try to access any static file in subdirectory I get lack of permissions. PHP calls seem to work fine.

So:

- when I try to request `localhost/LICENSE.txt` I get the license.
- when I try to access `localhost/test.php` or `localhost/app/test.php` it works fine
- when I try to access `localhost/app/test.html` I get Forbidden`in
  the browser and`client denied by server configuration:
  /var/www/localhost/htdocs/src/app/test.html` in error log

Of course files I try to request are in the right locations.

Here's `apache` version I am trying to run:

```
/var/www/localhost/htdocs # httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar 27 2018 11:32:10
```

Here's my `host` config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin test@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/htdocs/src
    ServerName schmidt.local

    <Directory "/var/www/localhost/htdocs/src">
        #
        # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
        AllowOverride All
        #
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        #
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine On

    </Directory>
    <LocationMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$">
        ProxyPass fcgi://php-fpm:7000/var/www/localhost/htdocs/src/$1
    </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

So as you can see I already have `request` instead of `allow` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19588786/401499).

Comment: it's not enough for the files to be in the right location, or for apache to allow requests through, the account that apache runs under must also have permission to access the file on disk. Check the permissions to the file.

Comment: So, a php file works and html doesn't? Is there an .htaccess file in this directory, forbidding the access?