# AH01630: client denied by server configuration but require all granted is set (Apache 2.4, CentOs)

Tags: apache, centos

I am using Apache 2.4 on CentOs to power my website. However, I always get a 403 forbidden error when trying to access the website through my browser. When I consulted the file `error_log` in the log directory of `/etc/httpd`, I repeatedly see the error:

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration

I have read in the Internet as well as in multiple StackOverflow questions that you can solve this error with `Require all granted` in the html directory configuration of the `httpd.conf` file (`/etc/httpd/conf/`).

I have configurated this directory (through which I am hosting my website) like recommended above (it was already configurated). The error persists, so there must be another problem in the server configuration that denies access to my website. My `httpd.conf` file is not changed at all, it is the default file that gets downloaded when installing Apache 2.4. Does anybody know why this error occurs? Can somebody explain to me what else can cause this error? I have looked everywhere in the internet for this error (links below) but nothing could help me at this problem.

I have no .htaccess file in my website. Only an index.html file to test it.

[Stack Overflow Question: "Apache2: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration)

[Apache Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration)

[Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/699781/ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration-apache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the whole HTTPD configuration and then reinstalled Apache. I had to enable PHP too by using these lines of code:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Then Apache worked flawlessly.