# WSGI file permissions issue

Tags: python, apache, flask, server

I have read through posts about similar issues but they all seem to be slightly different, and hence this post.

I have a domain with a website (eg. example.com) that works just fine. I am now in the process of creating a subdomain (eg. sub.example.com) ***with a Flask app*** (the main domain is not a Flask app) which is also connected to an SQLite database (in the same folder).

After setting the A record for the subdomain, when accessing the subdomain address I get the following error message in my browser: "Forbidden. You don't have permission to access this resource."

What am I doing wrong?

Apache's error log says:

```
[Mon Jan 06 15:48:21.300079 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 12194] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/user/show/application.wsgi
```

The folder permissions for the root folder that holds the main Flask file (application.py) are `drwxr-xr-x` (ie. `755`) and owner and group is my username. All files within that folder, and within the static and templates folders are `rwxr-xr-x` (ie. `755`). Since the Apache error log mentions application.***wsgi*** specifically, I double-checked the permissions on it and they are also `755`.

This is application.wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/user/show/")

from show import app as application
application.secret_key = '*******'
```

(As a footnote, do I perhaps need to set the secret key in environment variables - is that the issue? If so, how do I do that in this case?)

This is the .conf for the subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/show/application.wsgi
    <Directory /home/user/show/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /home/user/show/static
    <Directory /home/user/show/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:

[Apache2: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration)

Replacing all instances of

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

with

```
Require all granted
```