# an error with accessing a form using MAMP and cgi - Debugging

Tags: python, php, cgi, mamp

I am using MAMP and I have a folder named (QL) that has three separate forms (written in php).and a main form that communicating with all form using python cgi code. It works for all forms except one form and it shows the below error in the erro_log
Note : I do not know what is .DS_Store and when I search my device for it I found a History9.htm

when I print the request.reason it shows me that the error is 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

```
[Tue Feb 23 19:26:19 2021] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English
[Tue Feb 23 19:26:20 2021] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/QL/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost:8888/
[Tue Feb 23 19:26:38 2021] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/QL/Global/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost:8888/QL/
[Tue Feb 23 19:29:21 2021] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English
[Tue Feb 23 19:29:23 2021] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/QL/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost:8888/
```

Comment: Note : I do not know what is .DS_Store and when I search my device for it I found a History9.htm

Comment: Hi JustHope, You might need to provide more information to your post before someone might be able to help you with your situation. In the meantime, [.DS_Store files](https://fileinfo.com/extension/ds_store) are usually related to macOS and I don't know if these files are related to your issue at hand. I would recommend searching around for information related to your error `client denied by server configuration` online. I don't know if [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18392741/1167750) has information that can help, but I found it based on searching for your type of error message.