# "You don't have permission to access this resource." for perl scripts in CGI-Executables/ on Mac OS 11 - Big Sur

Tags: macos, apache, perl, httpd.conf, cgi-bin

I am receiving "You don't have permission to access this resource." for perl scripts in `/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/` on Mac OS 11 - Big Sur. I have a simple test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
print "<html>";
print "<body>";
print "Test Page";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
print "\n";
```

When I execute it from `Terminal`, it runs properly and its output is:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<html><body>Test Page</body></html>
```

I believe the file permissions for the script:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 <my-username>  wheel    170 Aug 31 04:50 test.pl*
```

are correct.

I believe the file permissions for the directory in which the script lives:

```
drwxr-xr-x  24 <my-username>  wheel   768 Aug 31 18:52 CGI-Executables/
```

are also correct.

I believe my `httpd.conf` is correctly configured:

```
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module>
        #LoadModule cgid_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_cgid.so                                                                                                          
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        LoadModule cgi_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
```

and

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables"

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .pm
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

While I believe all of this to be correct, clearly, one or more of these beliefs is false, because when I try to open `test.pl` in a web browser using `http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.pl` I get the error message:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

**EDIT**

After @ikegami 's suggestion that I look at the logs, I find in `/usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

`[Sat Sep 03 07:55:17.605501 2022] [authz_core:error] [pid 3035] [client ::1:61483] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executablestest.pl`

which led me to [Apache2: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration), and the suggestion that I modify my `httpd.conf`, adding:

```
    Order allow,deny
```

So, now my `httpd.conf` looks like:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables"

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .pm
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But after a `brew services restart httpd`, I am still getting the `AH01630` error above.

Comment: Permissions on www dir?

Comment: You shouldn;t be relying on what you see in the browser, but what you get in the logs!

Comment: @TLP permissions on ```/Library/WebServer/Documents``` and  ```/Library/WebServer/CGI-Exectuables``` are ```<my-username>:wheel```

Comment: Recent versions of MacOS have a feature which blocks access to the file system under some circumstances, are you bumping into that? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a kind of attention to details  test.

Look at very end of this

```
3035] [client ::1:61483] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executablestest.pl
```

And look at this

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables"
```

and change it to this

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/"
```