# AH01630:Client denied by server Configuration

Tags: php, angular

[web server error log messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v8Hi.png)
Publish web site through can upload small size IMG or pdf (less than 100kb) but cannot upload larger size IMG(png,jpg,jpeg) or PDF file (100kb=<). (backend is PHP frontend is Angular)

Comment: check this answer :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration)

Comment: check post_max size in your php.ini configuration file and change it to the size you want. After that restart your server.