# ERROR_403_ Forbidden

Tags: php, apache, web, ispconfig

I want to upload a job for my university (html + php ) ,when upload the project to server ,  the server display

---

ERROR 403 - Forbidden!
The following error occurred:
You are not permitted to access the requested URL.
Please contact the webmaster with any queries.
Powered by ISPConfig

---

and the error.log file is contains: AH01630: client denied by server configuration

i tried to change a permission of files to 777 but not work

Comment: `0777` is a security risk and shouldn't be used. Rather use `0755` or `0775`. Did you try and contact the support of the server in order to solve this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache2: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration)