Receiving 403 Forbidden Error in PHP on Ubuntu 22.04
I am encountering a persistent issue where I receive a 403 Forbidden error whenever I attempt to access any PHP file within directories on my Apache web server, except for index.php. This problem appeared suddenly without any recent major changes to the configuration.
Here are the details of the problem:

Error Details: When accessing PHP files like login_process.php within directories, I receive the 403 Forbidden error.
File Permissions: I have verified that file permissions are correctly set for the directories and files in question.
Apache Error Log: The Apache error log (/var/log/apache2/error.log) consistently shows entries like the following for files within my working directory:
[Time] [access_compat:error] [pid 841806] [client IP] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/example.com/dir/anyfile-except-index.php, referer: https://example.com/dir/
Apache Configuration (apache2.conf): My Apache configuration allows AllowOverride All and Require all granted within the <Directory /var/www/> block.

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

I have tried various troubleshooting steps, including checking Apache configurations, file permissions, and .htaccess files, but I have not been able to resolve this issue.
Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to debug and fix this 403 Forbidden error for PHP files within directories on my Apache web server?
Update: By setting AllowOverride None in apache2.conf solved my problem. But I wanted the custom .htaccess rules also in the directory to apply.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

//Proper Working Code - this can hardly be called "proper". Still not using prepared statements; still relying on passwords that apparently have been stored as plain text.

That Id and name was edited by me before uploading the code. In actual, it is all right. Now I also edited the question & previews it 2nd time also.

You need to go check your server configuration then. https://stackoverflow.com/q/18392741/1427878 has some hints on what to pay attention to, in case you perhaps recently switched from Apache 2.2 to 2.4

This was the testing application I developed I know that I do not store encrypted passwords, that is not a good practice. But to practice our main functionality in the code, I used it.

I tried the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top solution, but all things are already there in my configuration.

This error was raised by mine earlier time fault only. In the web root of our domain. This .htaccess code is there:
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>

So, after fixing the code, my project works properly.
Thanks all of you for my help in my own fault by giving your precious time.

This error means that your server is not allowing any requests and denies any incoming HTTP requests. To fix it, try adding the following configuration in your .htaccess file or your virtual host configuration file, whichever you see fit (I would personally add this to the virtual host file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/).
<Directory /var/www/example.com/>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
</Directory>


By trying your advice, my whole directory shows 403 forbidden error then.

Yes! I updated the apache2.conf code in question also as well. You can check it from there.

@TejaswaNama I just updated my answer with new content inside the  part, please try it now, should work.

You can see I already addded that configuration in my question only. It is already there.
